# Django sending email and get the recipient email from html input field

Tags: python, html, django

I have a django method to send an email. currently the email recipient is hardcoded in the code, how can I create a dynamically where on submit a field from html page it will immediately get the recipient email and execute the method

Html

```
<input id="recipient_email" type="email">
```

view.py

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

def send_email(subject, text_content, html_content, to):
    to = 'test_to@gmail.com'
    from_email = 'test_from@gmail.com'
    subject = 'New Project Created'
    text_content = 'A Test'
    html_content = """
        <h3 style="color: #0b9ac4>email received!</h3>
    """
    email_body = html_content
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, to)
    msg.attach_alternative(email_body, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do the work inside a view. Also, in order to send data to the server, you need to give a *name* to the input.

```
<input id="recipient_email" type="email" name="recipient_email_address">
```

Then, inside a Django view, you would get this input data like this:

If it was a **POST** request:

```
to = request.POST['recipient_email_address']
```

If it was a **GET** request:

```
to = request.GET['recipient_email_address']
```

Then you would pass the `to` variable as an argument to your `send_email` function.

Please note that the `to` argument in the `EmailMultiAlternatives` expects a `list`, instead of a `str`.

See below an example:

**index.html**

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input id="recipient_email" type="email" name="recipient_email_address">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def send_email_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        to = request.POST['recipient_email_address']
        send_email('subject of the message', 'email body', '<p>email body</p>', [to, ])
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Please consider using the Forms API when dealing with user input. [Read more about it in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/).